# form select change option from a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-block-level" ng-model="formData.coWorkers">
    <option value="">-- Choose amount of customers --</option>
    <option value="0-4">0 - 4</option>
    <option value="5-24">5 - 24</option>
    <option value="25-99">25 - 99</option>
    <option value="100-249">100 - 249</option>
    <option value="250-">over 250</option>                    
</select>
```

The formData.coWorkers can have this kind of info "50", "15-50" and "120-". The amount or range of coWorkers in a company.

What I want to do is the following:

- Look for the number in formData.coWorkers, ex. 15-50
- Split this information af first and pick the highest number (50)
- Look into select -> option value to find a number range that have 50 in it. The third option value "25-99"
- "15-50" should select "25-99"

But I have no idea how or where to start. Is there anyone that can help my out on this?

Kind regards,
Niels

Comment: Could you simplify your question a bit?

Comment: what's the highest number in "120-" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

In your view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.coWorkers" />

<select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-block-level" ng-model="selected" ng-options="r as r.text for r in ranges" >
    <option value="">-- Choose amount of customers --</option>                 
</select>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.ranges = [
    { text: "0 - 4",     min: 0, max: 4 }, 
    { text: "5 - 24",    min: 5, max: 24}, 
    { text: "25 - 99",   min: 25, max: 99},
    { text: "100 - 249", min: 100, max: 249}, 
    { text: "over 250",  min: 250}
];
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.$watch('formData.coWorkers', function(nv, ov) {
    if (nv) {
        var values = new String(nv).split('-');
        var min = new Number(values[0]).valueOf();
        var max = new Number(values[1]).valueOf();
        angular.forEach($scope.ranges, function(value, index) {
            if (min >= value.min && (max <= value.max || !max || !value.max)) {
                $scope.selected = value;
            } else if (max >= value.min) {
                $scope.selected = value
            }                
        });
    } else {
        $scope.selected = "";
    }
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/558/)

Comment: That is awesome. Exactly the way it should work, but how to do it where it choose the highest (30) or take the first number if the number is like this "30-" (30 coworkers and up).

Comment: That depends. If the user enter 30 now, it will select "25-99". I don't believe that "- 30" makes any sense. For the other side, when the user type "30 -", what should be selected? "25-99", "over 250", or other?

Comment: The data is taken from a webservice where they show number of coworkers like this: "xx" (15), "xx-xx" (15-50) and "xx-" (150-). So if we take these examples, the first should return "5 - 24", second "25 - 99" and third "100 - 249"

Comment: @NIKRI See if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/558/) answer your question. If so, update your question with this requirement ("15-50" should select "25-99") that I'll update my answer as well.

Comment: This is working exactly as it should. Thank you so much, I will update my question right away.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<script>
    function selectWorkersAmount(workersCount) {
        var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectbasic');
        for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) {
            var optionValue = selectBox.options[i].value;
            if (optionValue) {
                var range = optionValue.split("-");
                if (workersCount >= range[0]) {
                    if (workersCount <= range[1] || range[1] == "") {
                        selectBox.selectedIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-block-level" ng-model="formData.coWorkers">
        <option value="">-- Choose amount of customers --</option>
        <option value="0-4">0 - 4</option>
        <option value="5-24">5 - 24</option>
        <option value="25-99">25 - 99</option>
        <option value="100-249">100 - 249</option>
        <option value="250-">over 250</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button onclick="javascript:selectWorkersAmount(1);">1 worker</button><br>
    <button onclick="javascript:selectWorkersAmount(100);">100 workers</button><br>
    <button onclick="javascript:selectWorkersAmount(250);">250 workers</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but the angularJS part matched more the issue I had.